# Display split results in Symfony2 twig

Tags: php, symfony, split, twig

I have a function in my Symfony controller which returns the following:
**test+testString1+test2**

## TestController.php

```
public function getResultAction($fileName) {
    $string1="test";
    $string2="testString1";
    $string3="test2";
    $response = $string1."+".$string2."+".$string3;

    return new Response($response);
}
```

In my twig I've rendered the function in my controller:

## test.html.twig

```
{% set test %}
    {{ render(controller('TestBundle:Test:getResult')) }}|split('+', 4)
{% endset %}

{{ test[0] }}
```

I'm using twig split filter so that I can display *test*, *testString1* and *test2* individually. But then whenever I attempt to display **test[0]**, I receive the following error:

> Impossible to access a key "0" on an object of class "Twig_Markup" that does not implement ArrayAccess interface in TestBundle:Test:test.html.twig

What's wrong with what I'm doing? I hope you could help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the split filter inside the double brace as follow:

```
{% set test %}
    {{ render(controller('TestBundle:Test:getResult')) |split('+', 4) }}
{% endset %}
```

Hovenever seems same problem with the `set` tag. From the doc:

> The set tag can also be used to 'capture' chunks of text

Try with:

```
{% 
   set test=render(controller('TestBundle:Test:getResult'))|split('+', 4)
%}
```

Hope this help